# How can I stop Blender From Draining my Battery Life?

Tags: rendering

Since I started using Blender on my school MacBook Air,every time I render an image,it drains my battery life quickly and I have to put it back on the charger in less than two hours which is so annoying. Could someone please tell me how to fix this? If you do,I'll give you a big reward as well as my deepest thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you start rendering an image, Blender utilizes either your CPU or GPU and puts it under heavy load. If your CPU/GPU is under heavy load, it raises it's clock rate and therefor its voltage. This results in higher energy consumption. There is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Well that stinks!

Answer (score 2):

You can send the render job to a free, distributed renderfarm (eg. https://sheepit-renderfarm.com).

This will likely decrease the time taken to get the rendered result and use less of your laptop's energy.

Obviously, you should contribute to the renderfarm when you are plugged in

Comment: Which in return would bring him up to the same problem.

Comment: I don't let others do the renders for me. I like to do them all by myself. It makes me feel good after I created something.

Comment: How will it bring him to the same problem?

Comment: He's right,you know.

Comment: What I really wanted to know was how to reduce the amount of battery drainage when I'm rendering compared to what it's doing right now. I don't even have a GPU driver on this thing which probably means my luck is a joke.

Comment: @JeremiahTDK As it stands, your question is: How can I stop blender from draining my battery life [when rendering an image]? A solution is to let others do the rendering for you. If you do not want to let others render for you, modify your original post

Comment: The problem is, that if he uses Sheepit, he needs to participate, which in return drains his battery life.

Comment: @JeremiahTDK You can save a small amount of battery life (but not prevent if from "draining") by reducing the CPU load. Eg. do not display rendered tiles, but only display the finished frame at the end

Comment: @Reaper You are not required to participate. You _can_ participate. It is just that your project will be on a waitlist longer if you do not have a positive amount of points

Comment: Well, realistically, on the long run, you _need_ to participate.

Comment: @Reaper Actually, you don't _need_ to. The waitlist is usually only 6 to 10 hours - which is still faster than if I try to render my own projects myself

Comment: If you can afford, waiting 10 hours for _your first frame to start_, then yes, this is an option for you. However, we don't know about @JeremiahTDK situation. And we don't know if he's willing to wait that long.

Comment: Rendering takes CPU/GPU time and any such work will drain the battery. In my mind @arsyyuhjb’s suggestion is a valid one. The only other option is to reduce the work by reducing the quality and/or resolution of the render, simplifying the model, using BI instead of Cycles - or rendering when not running on battery (or get someone else to render it!). The question is otherwise too broad to dismiss this as a solution.